# Family tree recursive sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, family-tree

I'm trying to create sql query for family tree purpuses that loops through table according to row values of the table it self.

So I have table that has values

```
person id  | parent 1 | parent 2  
1          | 2        | 5  
2          | 3        | 4   
3          |          |  
4          |          |  
5          | 6        | 7   
6          |          | 5  
7          |          |
```

[image: family tree table]

and I want to select all the parets from the one I'm seaching to the oldest, after that search all of their offsping and after that their parents?

Examples

[image: search done with person 1]

Comment: [search done with person 2][3]
[search done with person 5][4]


  
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RGPA.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DplgJ.png

Comment: Kindly share sample data in formatted text (not images)

Comment: A recursive common table expression is commonly used for this type of query but unfortunately I don't think MySQL supports them.  I'd look at recursive CTE support/work-arounds in MySQL.

Comment: Which is your version of MySql?

Comment: Your text table shows an inconsistency: 6 is a parent of 5, and 5 is a parent of 6.